# Jenkins lists old branches when sending e-mail

Tags: git, jenkins, deployment, automation

Our company uses Jenkins to deploy our test system which includes the latest patches, so they can be tested. Everything is automated and broken into several steps. One step checks for branches (using GIT) in refs/remotes/origin which include a specific keyword (*todeploy* in this case). All branches that include this keyword are written into the e-mail for the other departments to see.

However for some reason old branches are also listed in the e-mail which of course causes confusion. Jenkins is supposed to delete these deployed branches afterwards which he does, but upon deploying again he somehow adds those old branches to the mail.

Here's what this build step looks like:

```
    def refs = "git for-each-ref --format=%(refname) refs/remotes/origin/*_todeploy_*".execute( null, workingDir )
refs.waitFor()
def patches = ""
def subject = "Tickets included in deployment ( "

def adresses = "random@email.com,"

refs.text.eachLine {

    patches += "<li>"+it.substring(it.lastIndexOf('MyTickets'),it.length())+"</li>"
    subject += it.substring(it.lastIndexOf('-')+1,it.length())+" "

}

String content = "<html><body>"+
   "Following tickets will be ready for testing shortly:"+
   "<ul>"+patches+"</ul>"
```

And the output equals something like:

- MyTicket 123
- MyTicket 456
- MyTicket 789

and this list just keeps on growing on every deployment, instead of not including the already deployed branchnames